# On Program Loading Event..?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Does anyone know what the onLoad() or similar Event is in Flex? I'm trying initialize, but no joy.

```
            protected function videoArea_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var currentPosition:int = videoArea.verticalScrollPosition;
            if (currentPosition < 0)
            {
                left_button.visible = false;
                right_button.visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: onload for what? when the flex app loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best alternative for `onLoad()` in Flex would be `creationComplete`.

See [this link (Adobe)](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=containers_intro_063_12.html) and [this link (MikaFlex)](http://www.mikaflex.com/?cat=79) for more information about the event hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to initialize?  If you're asking for the Flex Parallel to OnLoad(); perhaps you should tell us where onLoad() comes from?

I strongly suggest reading up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html).

You can do initalization in the constructor of a component.  If using MXML, you might want to use the [preinitialize](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:preinitialize) event.  Some folks also use [creationComplete](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:creationComplete).

Comment: creationComplete seems the way to go, yeah.. I was checking the XML Nodes to .length to decide whether the arrows are required to load or not.